# RewriteRule to match all characters

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So, I'm trying to write a htaccess file that will rewrite everything back to the root index file with a query added after it, so for example

`example.com/cheese/` will route to `example.com/index.php?cheese/`

`example.com/cheese` will route to `example.com/index.php?cheese`

`example.com/bob/fred` will orute to `example.com/index.php?bob/fred`

going in as many layers as necessary, does anyone have an suggestions?

Currently trying this but it isn't working:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?$1
```

I know it isn't working because I am testing it with the following and the query output is not correct.

```
<?php
    $page = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    echo $page;
?>
```

Comment: You should add more info, for example, if you've enabled the `mod_rewrite` module...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, `mod_rewrite` must be enabled.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /
      RewriteRule /(.*) index.php?$1
</IfModule>
```

But if using `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` is a necessity I'd suggest using:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /
      RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
```

and afterwards retrieve url from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, because your solution breaks every GET request.

Comment: Because when GET request parameters are sent in url via query string  in format `www.example.com/test?key1=value1&key2=value2` and when you apply your rule `www.example.com/index.php?test` it overrides the query string

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` will avoid looping and skip valid files like css, js images being rewritten to `index.php`.

Access the query string as:

```
$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]
```